# How is time complexities O(n) and O(kn) coming equal?

Tags: time-complexity

When dealing with time complexities, I have seen considering `O(n)` and `O(kn)` as equal. Consider constant `k` as an integer > 1. Any way `kn > n`, right?

Can someone explain this. I am not from Computer Science background.

Comment: this should probably be asked in the computer science stack exchange (http://cs.stackexchange.com/) - there are many questions like this in that forum. I will flag this question as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Big O Notation comes from a limit point of view and it has a very specific definition.

We say a function `f(x) is O(g(x))` if and only if, for very big values of `x`, `|f(x)| <= M * |g(x)|`, where `M` is a constant and `M > 0`.

This definition basically means that `O(kn)` is a subset of `O(n)`. Of course, an algorithm in `O(2n)` WILL always be faster than another one in `O(3n)`, but they all belong to the big family of `O(n)` algorithms.

They are considered equivalent, since when dealing with infinitely big numbers, nobody cares about constant anymore

[Wikipedia link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

Answer (score 1):

I have already commented this should be migrated to [cs.stackexchange.com](http://cs.stackexchange.com) (you will find far more detail about Big O analysis there), however the following is a brief answer:

Big O, Big Theta and Big Omega all deal with how something grows as the input size grows. It is a big picture view of things.

A high constant will affect the time it takes to run something, but the growth rate is still linear. Constants are dropped for the sake of looking at the big picture, ie what type of growth or what family of functions does this belong to. In your case it is the linear growth family.